# Spacewalk Install failed selinux

Tags: centos, selinux, spacewalk

Hi I am trying to configure spacewalk on a Centos 7 box for my organization.

I am following this guide;
https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall#installing-spacewalk

I am having two issues when installing  `spacewalk-selinux-2.3.2-1.el7.noarch` and
`osa-dispatcher-selinux-5.11.74-1.el7.noarch`

I get the errors:

```
Installing : spacewalk-selinux-2.3.2-1.el7.noarch Failed to resolve roletype statement at 
/etc/selinux/mls/tmp/modules/400/spacewalk/cil:2
/usr/sbin/semodule:  Failed!
Failed to resolve roletype statement at 
/etc/selinux/strict/tmp/modules/400/spacewalk/cil:2 
/usr/sbin/semodule:  Failed! Verifying  : spacewalk-selinux-2.3.2-1.el7.noarch
```

and also;

```
Installing : osa-dispatcher-selinux-5.11.74-1.el7.noarch
Failed to resolve roletype statement at 
/etc/selinux/mls/tmp/modules/400/osa-dispatcher/cil:2
/usr/sbin/semodule:  Failed!
Failed to resolve roletype statement at /etc/selinux/strict/tmp/modules/400/osa-dispatcher/cil:2
/usr/sbin/semodule:  Failed!
Verifying  : osa-dispatcher-selinux-5.11.74-1.el7.noarch
```

In `/etc/selinux/config` it is `SELINUX=enforcing` and `SELINUXTYPE=targeted`. result of `rpm -qa | grep selinux-policy` is `selinux-policy-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch` and `selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch`

I have enabled the CentOS-CR repo to resolve an earlier error when installing about not having http-parser dependencies.

I have also tried setting SeLinux to permissive but this didn't help.

Does anyone know how to resolve these selinux errors? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ignored the SeLinux errors, downgraded c3p0 from version 9.5 to 9.1, ran `rhn-satellite restart` and have now logged in to spacewalk. I also went in to vi `/etc/sysconfig/network` and added a `HOSTNAME=my.spacewalk.server` entry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using MLS selinux policy. Check `SELINUXTYPE=mls` in `/etc/selinux/config` and `rpm -qa |grep selinux-policy-`. While Spacewalk ships selinux policy for targeted, mls, and strict selinux, I am pretty sure that Spacewalk team tests only `targeted` policy.
So you either contact Spacewalk team and try to help them to debug the problem or you switch to targeted selinux.

And BTW howtoforge tutorial is nice, but you should rather follow what the team recommends: https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall

Comment: Hi in /etc/selinux/config it is `SELINUX=enforcing` and `SELINUXTYPE=targeted`. result of rpm -qa | grep selinux-policy is `selinux-policy-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch` and `selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch`

Comment: I have used the https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall tutorial as well, with the same outcome.